# How to make a foreach loop with 3 or more excel ranges using C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, interop, excel-interop

After searching alot and not being able to find something that I could adapt to my needs, I figured I'd try asking.
Basically what i need is a loop that would go through my entire range (usedRange)
and verify if on the same row, cells from 3 or more columns are empty (example A10, B10, C10) then the entire row should be removed.

One of my attempts as follows :

```
xl.Range emptyCellsDel = MySheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xl.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks);
        xl.Range myRange = emptyCellsDel.Range["A:C"];
        const int aCol = 1; const int bCol = 2; const int cCol = 3;
        for (int i = 1; i < MySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((MySheet.Cells[i, aCol].Value ?? "").ToString() == "" &&
                (MySheet.Cells[i, bCol].Value ?? "").ToString() == "" &&
                (MySheet.Cells[i, cCol].Value ?? "").ToString() == "")
            {
                myRange.EntireRow.Delete();
            }
        }
```

Any sort of Idea / suggestion would be awesome and much appreciated.
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You need to make note of the rows you want to delete and remove them outside of the for loop so that you are not modifying the range accessed by the for loop.

Also, if you are shifting the rows up you also need to remove them last row first so the row indexes do not get messed up. In the example below I have done this by reversing the order of the for loop and storing the row numbers in a list which will enforce the ordering.

```
xl.Range myRange = emptyCellsDel.Range["A:C"];
const int aCol = 1; const int bCol = 2; const int cCol = 3;
List<int> rowsToDelete = new List<int>();
int rowCount = MySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
for (int i = rowCount; i >= 1; i--)
{
    if ((MySheet.Cells[i, aCol].Value2 ?? "").ToString() == "" &&
        (MySheet.Cells[i, bCol].Value2 ?? "").ToString() == "" &&
        (MySheet.Cells[i, cCol].Value2 ?? "").ToString() == "")
    {
        rowsToDelete.Add(i);
    }
}
foreach (int row in rowsToDelete) { ((Range)(MySheet.Rows[row])).Delete(XlDirection.xlUp); }
```

Comment: I've tried it but for some reason, it doesn't remove any empty rows.

Comment: Try switching .Value to .Value2 the cells may have some formatting (like date/time) which returns a type with a non blank default value.

Comment: @JohnG Crap your right. I swear I made that change, I guess it didn't make it into my answer. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As SmStroble answer indicates and I have mentioned before. If you start at the TOP of the excel file and delete empty rows, you will run into an indexing issue when you delete a row and shift the others up, the row indexing in the loop will get thrown off. In the `for` loop code you have posted that variable would be `i`. Using this approach will miss empty rows and possibly delete non-empty rows.

SmStroble’s answer is the correct way to fix this issue, however there a couple of issues. First as commented we want to delete rows from the bottom up so SmStroble’s solution is to loop through the rows to find the row indexes of the empty rows and place them in a `List<int>`. The only problem here is that when you use a `foreach` loop here it will start with the first item put in the list, not the last.

The second issue you may run into is execution time. Looping through Excel rows can be expensive. When you use the following `MySheet.UsedRange` line in a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < MySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++) {…
```

This line is expensive. If there are a lot of rows in the sheet this could take a significant amount of time. There are other solutions for this however a simple solution is to simply make an `int` variable to hold the row count and use it in the `for` loop like below:

```
int totalRows = MySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 1; i < totalRows; i++) {
```

This small change will speed up execution significantly depending on the number of rows in the spreadsheet. Using a test sheet with 730+ rows it took 2447 Milliseconds with the `UsedRange` in the `for` loop and 1118 milliseconds when the `usedRange` was outside the `for` loop. Hope this helps.

```
  string filePath = @"C:\YourPathToExcelFile\YourExcelFile.xls";
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  ExcelApp.Visible = true;
  Workbooks wbs = ExcelApp.Workbooks;
  Workbook xlWorkbook = wbs.Open(filePath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
  Excel._Worksheet MySheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
  const int aCol = 1;
  const int bCol = 2;
  const int cCol = 3;
  List<int> rowsToDelete = new List<int>();
  int totalRows = MySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
  for (int i = totalRows; i > 0; i--) {
    if ((MySheet.Cells[i, aCol].Value ?? "").ToString() == "" &&
        (MySheet.Cells[i, bCol].Value ?? "").ToString() == "" &&
        (MySheet.Cells[i, cCol].Value ?? "").ToString() == "") {
      rowsToDelete.Add(i);
    }
  }

  foreach (int row in rowsToDelete) {
    ((Range)(MySheet.Rows[row])).Delete(XlDirection.xlUp);
  }

  xlWorkbook.Save();
  xlWorkbook.Close();
  ExcelApp.Quit();
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);

  Console.WriteLine("Fished processing! Press any key to exit");
  Console.ReadKey();
```

**EDIT:** changed the code above to loop from the bottom of the excel file to the top. This avoids having to reverse the `rowsToDelete` list.

Comment: I've tried it like this as well but I can't seem to make it work.
I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I intend to fiddle with it until I can make it work.
The excel file that it usually works on has roughly 20.000-30.000 rows.
The way that I managed to make this work so far (but I've tried to make it a bit more fancy) was by filterin in my first column, then knowing that sometimes my 2nd and 3rd column may have blanks, I filter those out, thus getting the blank rows, and deleting them. But I wanted to go a bit "bigger & better" about it.
I'll post an update a.s.a.p. Thank you !